# Checkbox becomes unclickable after checkbox limit function occur reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, checkbox, ecmascript-6

I have a mapping function which shows JSON values into checkboxes, each checkbox triggers another 2 checkboxes, the JSON I am using have a min/max value which I made a function for to set min/max for checkbox selections in each section. My problem is that once the parent & child checkboxes are clicked and then I redo the process where I click it to shrink it and click it again to expand it, the children checkboxes stops being clickable.

The checkbox values are passed as props from **Checkbox.js** to **Itemlist.js** where the fetch/map happens.

React Live Snippet: https://codesandbox.io/embed/2178pwz6or?fontsize=14

**Checkbox.js**

```
class Checkboxes extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentData: 0,
      limit: 2,
      checked: false
    };
  }

  selectData(id, event) {
    let isSelected = event.currentTarget.checked;
    if (isSelected) {
      if (this.state.currentData < this.props.max) {
        this.setState({ currentData: this.state.currentData + 1 });
      } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.currentTarget.checked = false;
      }
    } else {
      if (this.state.currentData > this.props.min) {
        this.setState({ currentData: this.state.currentData - 1 });
      } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.currentTarget.checked = true;
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    const input2Checkboxes =
      this.props.options &&
      this.props.options.map(item => {
        return (
          <div className="inputGroup2">
            {" "}
            <div className="inputGroup">
              <input
                id={this.props.childk + (item.name || item.description)}
                name="checkbox"
                type="checkbox"
                onChange={this.selectData.bind(
                  this,
                  this.props.childk + (item.name || item.description)
                )}
              />
              <label
                htmlFor={this.props.childk + (item.name || item.description)}
              >
                {item.name || item.description}{" "}
                {/** <img src={this.props.img} alt="" /> <span className="pricemod">{props.childprice} SAR</span>
                 */}
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      });

    return (
      <form className="form">
        <div>
          {/** <h2>{this.props.title}</h2>*/}
          <div className="inputGroup">
            <input
              id={this.props.childk + this.props.name}
              name="checkbox"
              type="checkbox"
              checked={this.state.checked}
              onChange={this.selectData.bind(
                this,
                this.props.childk + this.props.uniq
              )}
              onChange={() => {
                this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked });
              }}
            />
            <label htmlFor={this.props.childk + this.props.name}>
              {this.props.name}{" "}
            </label>
          </div>{" "}
          {this.state.checked ? input2Checkboxes : undefined}
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Checkboxes;
```

Comment: your if statement -> should be greater than and equal to the object checkbox defined.
@Iankovova spotted it accurately!.
"(this.state.currentData >= this.props.min)"

Comment: @Shaze it works 2 times and it stops working check here https://codesandbox.io/embed/2178pwz6or?fontsize=14

Comment: It doesn't stop working here for me, which web browser are you using?

Comment: chrome, I edited the comment it doesn't crash but it stops working, so if you do side collection 1 > side 1 >side collection 1 > then side 1 click isn't clickable https://codesandbox.io/embed/2178pwz6or?fontsize=14

Comment: Ahh, now i know what exactly you mean. i just tried it out...

Comment: Yeah i guess the values get stuck at some point

Comment: After clicking multiple times on parent this unclickable issue seem to have gone, but you need to re-create your if statement with something more dynamic.
For now it works with this:
Line no. 17

" if (this.state.currentData = this.props.max) { "

Comment: Did you try the above?

Comment: Yes, & it made the min/max selection limit function stop working, anyways thank you for your time and cooperation, @alvinlee's answer has pointed out the problem and its solution and it made it work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help you see *why* you're encountering the issue, you can modify the `selectData` method of `Checkbox.js` with some helpful debugging statements:

```
// Checkbox.js

  selectData(id, event) {
    let isSelected = event.currentTarget.checked;
    console.log(
      `Attempting to ${isSelected ? "check" : "uncheck"} ${
        event.currentTarget.id
      }`
    );
    console.log(`min is ${this.props.min}, max is ${this.props.max}`);
    console.log(`currentData is: ${this.state.currentData}`);

    if (isSelected) {
      if (this.state.currentData < this.props.max) {
        console.log('Allowed to check. Incrementing currentData')
        this.setState({ currentData: this.state.currentData + 1 });
      } else {
        console.log('Not allowed to check: greater than or equal to max')
        event.preventDefault();
        event.currentTarget.checked = false;
      }
    } else {
      if (this.state.currentData > this.props.min) {
        console.log('Allowed to uncheck. Decrementing currentData')
        this.setState({ currentData: this.state.currentData - 1 });
      } else {
        console.log('Not allowed to uncheck. Less than or equal to min')
        //  event.preventDefault();
        // event.currentTarget.checked = true;
       }
    }
  }
```

You'll notice, as you check "Side 1" and then un-check it, that you do not satisfy the condition `if (this.state.currentData > this.props.min)`, and so you never get to actually decrement `this.state.currentData`.

To fix this, you need to do one of 2 things:

- Change your conditional to be `if (this.state.currentData >= this.props.min)`

OR

- Change your `data.json` to set your `min` to 0 rather than 1.

### UPDATE

You also have an issue when you do the following steps:

- Check a side collection (reveals sides)
- Check a side (increments `currentData`)
- Uncheck the side collection (hides sides)
- Check the side collection again

  - At this point, your sides are revealed, *but they are unchecked*
  - **AND** your `currentData` is already 1.
  - You cannot check any sides because of this.

To fix this, you can either:

- Reset `currentData` to 0 whenever the side collection is checked/un-checked.

OR

- Change your `input2Checkboxes` method to take into account which sides have been checked and keep their states, even if the side collection gets unchecked.

The first of the above 2 options is simpler to do. Within the `render` method of `Checkbox.js`, you need your side collection input's `onChange` to look like this:

```
// Checkbox.js

onChange={() => {
  this.setState({
    checked: !this.state.checked,
    currentData: 0
  })
}}
```

I've updated the forked code sandbox to show the working demo now:

[image: Edit Checkboxes Validation min]

Comment: Thank you for your answer its appreciated, but if you check this update https://codesandbox.io/embed/2178pwz6or?fontsize=14,  if you do side collection 1 > side 1 >side collection 1 > then side 1 click isn't clickable https://codesandbox.io/embed/2178pwz6or?fontsize=14

Comment: @Alpub You're right. I am seeing the issue you are facing now. When you check a collection, and then you check on a side within it - then un-check the selection, then re-check the selection: the `currentData` is still 1, but the sides show up un-checked, and you're not allowed to check them because you've hit the max. Let's see if we can fix this...

Comment: @Alpub Updates made to answer... check it out.

Comment: it works, thanks a lot for your answer and your detailed explanation

Answer (score 2):

In your code sandbox snippet, just change line 24 in Checkbox.js component to this

`if (this.state.currentData >= this.props.min) {`

Comment: @Iankovova thank you for your answer, but it works 1 or 2 times and it stops working, check here https://codesandbox.io/embed/2178pwz6or?fontsize=14

Comment: @Alpub I see. It stops working when you check item with one of it children and then uncheck item itself, leaving children checked